# Coffee on daily basis

Tags: health

I was wondering if coffee has serious health issues because I take coffee on daily basis. Can anyone tell me what are the possible health issues on consuming the coffee on daily basis?

Comment: This question seems to be very broad. Could you edit it to make it more specific? Also, you are making an incorrect assumption: Coffee is unhealthy when consumed on a daily basis. Coffee can be healthy when consumed in moderation. If you want to discuss this, feel free to tag me in the chatroom or in the meta forums.

Comment: Agreed, should be more specific. Are you looking for any specific health issues in particular?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Coffee and in particular caffeine, has had a reputation of being bad for your health, possibly being associated with cardiovascular disease, stroke, and your heart health in general.  [Current consensus](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/12/upshot/more-consensus-on-coffees-benefits-than-you-might-think.html?_r=0&abt=0002&abg=1) is that there may actually be some health benefits from drinking coffee, and those that drink moderate amount of coffee (3-5 cups) have lower risk with these particular issues.

A couple of things to note, these results have been found to be associated with black coffee, not including the effects of sweeteners or dairy added to the drink.  These additions may have other effects stemming from the sugars they add to you beverage. Also, some evidence has been found linking coffee prepared in a method that does not use a paper filter (e.g. french press) with increased [cholesterol levels](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/6242467/ns/health-heart_health/t/coffee-cholesterol/#.VVzrbmPr99Q).

Answer (score 3):

Numerous studies have found positive health benefits to regular coffee consumption, if done in moderation and without adding a lot of cream and sugar.  Specifically, coffee has the following health benefits:

**Huge Source of Antioxidants** - Coffee is the number one source of antioxidants. Antioxidants are important in fighting inflammation, which is linked to arthritis, many types of cancer, cardiovascular disease, etc.

**May protect against Type 2 Diabetes** - A number of studies have found that coffee drinkers have a much lower risk of getting Type 2 Diabetes.  One study suggests that the risk of Diabetes drops by 7% for each daily cup of coffee.

**May help protect against cognitive decline, Alzheimer's, and Dementia** - Study found that drinking coffee was associated with a 65% decreased risk of Alzheimer's and Dementia.

**May lower risk of Parkinson's** - Various studies have concluded that consuming coffee (and specifically, caffeine) are associated with lower incidences of Parkinson's disease.

**May lower risk of heart disease** - Study found that moderate coffee drinkers had a 20% lower risk of heart disease vs. non-drinkers, heavy-drinkers, or light-drinkers.

**May protect your liver** - Coffee consumption has been linked with decreased risk of liver cancer and Cirrhosis.

**Contains essential nutrients** - including Riboflavin (Vitamin B2), Pantothenic Acid (Vitamin B5), Manganese, Potassium, Magnesium, and Niacin (B3).

**May lower risk of Depression** - Multiple studies have linked coffee consumption with lower rates of depression.

**May lower risk of Gout** - Independent studies suggest that drinking coffee reduces the risk of developing Gout.

**Short-term boost in memory, mood, and general cognitive function** - In various studies, caffeine has been shown to provide short-term boosts in memory and cognition.

**Can increase fat burning and physical performance** - Caffeine has been shown to increase metabolic rate and adrenaline levels.

But there are some Cons of Drinking Coffee

> The potential health benefits of drinking coffee are exciting news, but that doesn’t mean more is better. For some people, coffee can
>   cause irritability, nervousness or anxiety in high doses, and it can
>   also impact sleep quality and cause insomnia. In people with
>   hypertension, coffee consumption does transiently raise their blood
>   pressure–although for no more than several hours–but no correlation
>   has been found between coffee drinking and long-term increases in
>   blood pressure or the incidence of cardiovascular disease in patients
>   with pre-existing hypertension.
>
> Caffeine affects every person differently, so if you experience any
>   negative side effects, consider cutting your coffee consumption
>   accordingly. It takes about six hours for the effects of caffeine to
>   wear off, so limit coffee drinking to early in the day, or switch to
>   decaf, which only contains about 2 to 12 mg of caffeine per eight
>   ounces. Always taper your coffee consumption gradually. Avoid quitting
>   coffee cold turkey; doing so can lead to caffeine withdrawal symptoms
>   that may include severe headache, muscle aches and fatigue which can
>   last for days.

**To Keep it Healthy**  Skip the fat-filled, sugar-laden coffeehouse beverages and order a basic black coffee. Alternatively, switch to skim milk or unsweetened soy or nut milk.

**Source**

[10 Healthy Reasons to Drink Coffee](http://www.onemedical.com/blog/newsworthy/10-healthy-reasons-to-drink-coffee-2/)

**Some more links you need to refer :**

[13 Proven Health Benefits of Coffee](http://authoritynutrition.com/top-13-evidence-based-health-benefits-of-coffee/)

PS : Will frequently update question and also provide some more links if i find any.

Answer (score 1):

Like Steven said, it's not accounting sweeteners. But if you are heavy on that sweet n low like I am, you may want to read [this](http://health.howstuffworks.com/wellness/food-nutrition/facts/artificial-sweetners-unhealthy-eco.htm) article.

Answer (score 1):

Excess coffee can hurt you but i found a way to keep it safe:
Use dark chocolate on daily basis, dark I mean 72% and up, better the 85, 90 or 99(unprocessed chocolate to keep nutrients). 
I was feeling the heart till discovered dark chocolate benefits combined with coffee. Also use less sugar as possible and if you use just keep with raw sugar (brown organic). I'm a heavy coffee drinker and so far no side effects. 
Hope will help the info.

Links bellow does show some benefits of the dark chocolate and coffee.

[7 Heart-Healthy Perks of Dark Chocolate](https://www.yahoo.com/health/7-heart-healthy-perks-of-dark-chocolate-94079824823.html)

[Coffee and Your Health](http://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/coffee-new-health-food?page=2)

Comment: Gotta love the 90% stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can find a review of recent studies regarding the effects of coffee on health here: 
[Coffee and Health: A Review of Recent Human Research.](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10408390500400009)

Taken from the abstract of the review paper in case you don't have access:

> *Unfiltered coffee is a significant source of cafestol and kahweol, which are diterpenes that have been implicated in the
>   cholesterolraising effects of coffee. The results of epidemiological
>   research suggest that coffee consumption may help prevent several
>   chronic diseases, including type 2 diabetes mellitus, Parkinson’s
>   disease and liver disease (cirrhosis and hepatocellular carcinoma).
>   Most prospective cohort studies have not found coffee consumption to
>   be associated with significantly increased cardiovascular disease
>   risk. However, coffee consumption is associated with increases in
>   several cardiovascular disease risk factors, including blood pressure
>   and plasma homocysteine. At present, there is little evidence that
>   coffee consumption increases the risk of cancer. For adults consuming
>   moderate amounts of coffee (3–4 cups/d providing 300–400 mg/d of
>   caffeine), there is little evidence of health risks and some evidence
>   of health benefits. However, some groups, including people with
>   hypertension, children, adolescents, and the elderly, may be more
>   vulnerable to the adverse effects of caffeine. In addition, currently
>   available evidence suggests that it may be prudent for pregnant women
>   to limit coffee consumption to 3 cups/d providing no more than 300
>   mg/d of caffeine to exclude any increased probability of spontaneous
>   abortion or impaired fetal growth.*